# Test Template with Robot Framework cannot use variables

Tags: robotframework

I have some problems using the robotframework template,how to get variables passed to the template?
Here is my code:

```
*** Keywords ***
re-random-value
    ${random int} =    Evaluate    random.randint(1, 5)
    [Return]    ${random-num}


*** Test Cases *** test1
    [Template]    test template
    re-random-value   # random-num is return value from keywords re-random-value


*** Keywords ***
   test template
    [Arguments]    ${random-num}
    log    ${random-num}
```

when I run the test case `test1`, The result is `re-random-value`, not the number of values returned by the keyword `re-random-value` I expected

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on Robot Framework [Test Templates](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates) states the following:

> ... test cases with template contain only the arguments for the
>   template keyword.

Within the context of a test template an argument can never be a keyword, the approach in the example won't work as is.

Assuming for a moment that the keyword may change per line/test case an intermediate keyword can be constructed that takes the name of the keyword as an argument and executes it. In the below updated version of your example this is what is done. Using the FOR loop to generate multiple values.

```
*** Test Cases *** 
test1
    [Template]    test template
        FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    1    5    
            re-random-value   # random-num is return value from keywords re-random-value
        END

*** Keywords ***
test template
    [Arguments]    ${keyword}
    ${value}    Run Keyword    ${keyword}
    Log To Console    ${value}

re-random-value
    ${random int} =    Evaluate    random.randint(1, 5)    modules=random
    [Return]    ${random int}
```

Results in (bear in mind the randomness of the values):

```
==============================================================================
test1                                                                 1
3
2
3
| PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: _"Given that an argument can never be a keyword"_ - that is not true. Keywords can be passed as arguments to other keywords. For example, you pass a keyword as an argument to the `Run keyword` keyword.

Comment: I think you're still incorrect. I could create a test template that accepts a keyword as an argument. In fact, doesn't your example show exactly that? You have an argument named `${keyword}`.

Comment: The example provides a value that is then interpreted in the template keyword as an value argument. My interpretation of the question is that the called keyword returns a value that is called directly by the template Test case. Technically different, but functionally similar.